# What's the best way to handle either a single value or an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to write a method that accepts either a single value or an array. What's the best idiom for doing this in Ruby?

Here are a couple things I've thought of:

```
def do_something(items)
  [*items].each { |item| ... }
end
```

I like the conciseness of that one, but it isn't clear unless you're used to this syntax

This next one just feels like too much code.

```
def do_something(items)
  items = [items] unless items.respond_to? :each
  items.each { |item| ... }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Kernel#Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) method works well here and is intended to be used to coerce things to an array:

```
irb(main):001:0> def my_length(item_or_array)
irb(main):002:1>   Array(item_or_array).length
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> my_length('one')
=> 1
irb(main):005:0> my_length([1, 2, 3])
=> 3
```